# Can anyone help me, I am stuck and can't figure the useRef Hook in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

Can someone explain to me if we can't create a reference in functional components, how is useRef creating a ref?
Take this code for example -

```
import "./styles.css";
import {useRef} from "react";

const App = () => {
  const inputElement = useRef();

  const focusInput = () => {
    inputElement.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" ref={inputElement} />
      <button onClick={focusInput}>Focus Input</button>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: "if we can't create a reference in functional components" — You can. As you demonstrated. What makes you think you can't?

Comment: They are called [Function Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). They are (generally) not [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In class based components, refs are created using `React.createRef()` in the constructor. (See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref)

The constructor is executed only once at the start. When the component is rendered / updated as necessary multiple times, the `render` method is executed for each render.

However in function components, the component *is* the `render` method. So, to avoid creating a ref during each render, the `useRef` reusues the ref, which was created once. (See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

> The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.